# When i save an list of objects offline by using sharedpreference in flutter it automatically convert to a string...the output is given below

Tags: flutter

Expected result is:

```
[
  {"name":"Indicator","remark":"N/A","point":0}, 
  {"name":"ggggggggggggggggg","remark":"Very Good","point":3},
  {"name":"THREE","remark":"Average","point":1}
].
```

The result that I have got:

```
"[
  {name: Indicator, remark: N/A, point: 0}, 
  {name: ggggggggggggggggg, remark: Very Good, point:3}, 
  {name: THREE, remark: Average, point: 1}
]"
```

> The whole result is in one string

Comment: How do you save the list of object in your shared preferences? Because if you are using the `.toString()` method is correct what you find out. You need to use the `json.encode(...your list...)` instead and save the result of it. Then to retrieve your list you will need to use the `json.decode(...string from shared...)`.

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences supports only a few types, which does not include `List`. If it is not a supported type, `SharedPreferences` calls `toString()` and saves the result.

If you want to store a list, you should use `jsonEncode(...)` and `jsonDecode(...)` to store your objects as String in `SharedPreferences`.

```
extension listStorage on SharedPreferences{
   List? getList(String key) {
      String? result = get(key);
      return result == null ? null : jsonDecode(result);
   }

   void setList(String key, List? list) => setString(key, list == null ? null : jsonEncode(list));
}
```

Note that all objects in the list must be json encodeable.